# Unable to import os.log in Kotlin Multiplatform

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I am trying to implement kotlin multiplaform logger. During the implementation of iOS architecture, I couldn't import os.log to use os_log. How could I do this or what else can I use to log in iOS in Kotlin Multiplatform project?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the `OSLog` class has only Swift API: see [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/oslog?language=objc). As Kotlin/Native does not provide direct interoperability, some frameworks are unavailable(see the same problem with SwiftUI for example). The best option you have out-of-the-box is to use `NSLog`, as Philip suggests, or to use some third-party library.

There is a resource with a list of popular Kotlin Multiplatform libraries: https://github.com/AAkira/Kotlin-Multiplatform-Libraries#logging. It might be a good place to start. Two important things to note about this:

1. This list does not include all libraries. For sure, there are some nice libs that are not included yet.
2. I'm recommending it as an entry point to the community. Philips' advice is pretty good, and maybe there are some other approaches that can be seen across the libs or in the kotlinlang Slack.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use kotlin `println`, also in iOS part you can use `platform.Foundation.NSLog` for formatter output

Comment: But I need to use something, that I can log with different types for example: info, warning, error, debug. With println and NSLog I can't do that, always is the same log.

Comment: I'd probably have to reimplement it by my hands in this case. you can check out how napier does that: https://github.com/AAkira/Napier/blob/master/napier/src/iosMain/kotlin/com/github/aakira/napier/DebugAntilog.kt
But if you want it to be fully native I think you should open a bug on https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/ - probably "os" framework is not in the list of generated ones, maybe there's some gradle option to include it

Answer (score 0):

val TAG = "Event"

Use this format

```
fun printLog(msg: String) {
   NSLog("$TAG $msg") 
}
```

Don't use like this.

```
 NSLog(TAG, msg)
```

I don't know the reason but it worked for me.